# How to compare date in Jooq

Tags: jooq

In the `mysql` db I have a field name `date` type `date`

the value of the field is as following `2019-11-05`

how to query in jooq where date is mentioned as above

I tried following

```
java.util.Date date = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2019-11-05")`
```

then

```
.where(DAILY_TRX_SUMMARY.DATE.eq(java.sql.Date(date.getTime()))
```

But it is not returning result.

What is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `java.sql.Date.valueOf("2019-11-05")` instead. Otherwise, you inherit JDBC's bad API design decisions, where a `java.sql.Date` might have timestamp information in some time zone.

Comment: It also does not work. I think it creates a date one day before. e.g. for date `2019-11-05` it creates sql date `2019-11-04`

Comment: @SazzadIslam: Somewhere between your client and server, you have wrong time zones configured. This is not something you can get right in your client code. Make sure all your different systems (including your database session) use the correct timezones.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I am getting "The method lt(Timestamp) in the type Field<Timestamp> is not applicable for the arguments (Date)".  It worked for you?

Comment: @TonyB: This question compares a `date` with a `date`. You can aska  new question about how to compare a `timestamp` with a `date`, if you want?